# Are there any gltf example datasets available?

Tags: webgl, vertex-buffer-object, data-structure, gltf, buffers

I'm currently researching my options on effeciently exchanging data for a webgl application. I understand the gltf format is still being [drafted](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/README.md) but I need some example data to understand whether this format is really useful for my application.

I'm currently using JSON data and I need to figure out whether there are any benefits to using data formats which are closer to the hardware. As far as I understand gltf also uses some JSON structures.

Are there any gltf example datasets available already?

Comment: I'm afraid resource requests are off topic. Ironically I only spotted this was off topic because of the recent edit... This could potentially be edited to ask specifically for details of the benefits of this data format, but after the time since posting and the existing answers, such a significant change is probably better posted as a brand new question. Feel free to pop into [chat] if you have any queries (or anyway...).

Comment: Fair enough. I was looking for a mininal working example anyways and solved that via [this thread](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/1934/361).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also check out the glTF models used in Cesium:

- https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/tree/master/Apps/SampleData/models
- https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/tree/master/Specs/Data/Models

Patrick

Comment: thanks, they even have binary gltf (`.bgltf`) versions available! +1

Answer (score 2):

Ok sometimes you have to ask a question to figure out the answer already.

Example datasets are available in the same repository as linked in the question already.

Here are some:

- [supermurdoc.gltf](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/e9cf7b0de2d1daed58317f5e6c8b9a2b7d543375/model/SuperMurdoch/SuperMurdoch.gltf)
- [duck.gltf](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/e9cf7b0de2d1daed58317f5e6c8b9a2b7d543375/model/duck/duck.gltf)
- [etc. pp.](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/sampleModels)