# Is it possible to store the plain buffer data in gltf files?

Tags: webgl, data-structure, vertex-buffer-object, gltf

The GL Transmission Format comes along with a JSON styled main file which basicly describes the scene and binary files which contain the buffers.

[image: gltf basic structure]

I'm currently writing a WebGL library and I need to work alot with the vertex and index buffers. So, my question now is:

Would it be possible to store plain text array buffers in the gltf (e.g., as JSON) instead of generating binary blobs always when the buffers are adjusted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to store the plain text array buffers in gltf, however, here is the code I use to generate buffers in JavaScript:

```
let vtx = [
  0.0857, 0.0759,
  0.0367, 0.9726,
  0.9678, 0.0318,
  0.9754, 0.9327
];

let idx = [
  0, 2,
  2, 4,
  4, 0,
  0, 1,
  1, 4
];

let buf = new ArrayBuffer(52);
let dat = new DataView(buf, 0, 52);

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i += 2) {
  dat.setUint16(i, idx[i / 2], true);
}

for (var v = 20; v < 52; v += 4) {
  dat.setFloat32(v, vtx[(v - 20) / 4], true);
}

let b64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(buf)));

window.console.log("data:application/octet-stream;base64," + b64);
```

Where `buf` contains the binary data in a JavaScript ArrayBuffer object and `b64` finally a base64 encoded string:

```
data:application/octet-stream;base64,AAACAAIABAAEAAAAAAABAAEABAB7g689dnGbPb1SFj1Q/Hg/vsF3P7hAAj3Qs3k/bcVuPw==
```

Comment: check out [this answer](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/3623/19180) to know how to decode the buffer data after encoding it using above method.

Answer (score 4):

Embedding human readable data is not supported. However you can put the data into a [data uri](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) to store the data inline in base64 format.

```
"buffers": {
    "a-buffer-id": {
        "byteLength": 1024,
        "type": "arraybuffer",
        "uri"="data:application/octet-stream;base64,..."
    }
},
```