# How to generate binary gltf array buffers?

Tags: data-structure, gltf, buffers

I'm looking for any way which enables me to quickly generate gltf files including the conversion of plain array buffers (vertex, index, color, etc.) into binary (bgltf, glb, bin) files.

I'm asking because it currently looks like there are only high level applications like Maya, Blender available which can do that or converters to indirectly write glTF from COLLADA.

Are there any way to generate binary gltf array buffers using low level / command line utilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally managed to write the buffers myself using [JavaScript](https://jsfiddle.net/6cevt681/1/).

The result is a base64 encoded String, like:

```
data:application/octet-stream;base64,AAACAAIABAAEAAAAAAABAAEABAB7g689dnGbPb1SFj1Q/Hg/vsF3P7hAAj3Qs3k/bcVuPw==
```

If you paste this Data URI into the browser, you can download a binary blob which is exactly what the glTF files can use.

[image]

The 52 bytes in this case contain 10 indices of 2 bytes size (`U_SHORT`) and 8 vertices of 4 bytes size (`FLOAT`), so `10 * 2 B + 8 * 4 B = 52 B`.

See [this post](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/3624/361) to find out how I generated the buffer and see [this answer](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/3623/361) on how to read the data again.

Answer (score 2):

Technically any file format where you can dump the entire file into a VBO and then render from that will work for the .bin files. Unfortunately those formats are less well known than they should be.

Then you only need to adjust the bufferview elements to reference the proper subset of the file